# How to convert Audible AAX file audiobook M4B on a Mac using Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, audio, audiobook

How do you convert Audible AAX files to M4B audiobooks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## How to convert Audible AAX files to M4B Audiobook

1. Open terminal by pressing `CMD + Space` and then typing "terminal".

[image]

2. Once terminal is open, paste the following command and click enter:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
   ```

   [image]
3. Follow the instructions given (pressing enter, typing password, ect...)

[image]

4. Once Homebrew is installed, paste the following command: `brew install ffmpeg` and press enter.
5. Now paste `brew install cask` and press enter.
6. Paste `brew cask install chromedriver` and press enter. If you get an error, you can use `brew install chromedriver -cask`.
7. Paste `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` and press enter.
8. Paste `python get-pip.py` and press enter.

- If you get an error about the version of Python, paste `python3 get-pip.py` instead to force it to use the Python 3 version.

9. Paste `pip install selenium requests` and press enter.
10. Paste `git clone https://github.com/inAudible-NG/audible-activator` and press enter.

10b. If you have a one-time password, please use `git clone https://github.com/weliveindetail/audible-activator/tree/pause-enter-otp` instead.

11. Paste `cd audible-activator` and press enter.
12. Paste `sed -i '' 's,chromedriver_path = "./chromedriver",chromedriver_path = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver",' audible-activator.py` and press enter.
13. Paste `python audible-activator.py` and press enter.

- If you had to use 'python3' in the command above in step 8, paste `python3 audible-activator.py` here.

14. Now, enter your Audible account username and password.
15. Enter your one-time password (if you have one) and go to terminal and press enter.

- You may get a pop-up about 'chromedriver' not being a signed application. Click 'Cancel' then go to System preferences > Security > General tab and click the allow button. Then try running the command again.

16. Terminal should print your 8 digit activation key.
17. Paste `ffmpeg -activation_bytes <<<YOUR KEY HERE>>> -i`  (replacing `<<<YOUR KEY HERE>>>` with your 8 digit activation key), then drag your Audible AAX file into terminal, paste  `-c copy ~/Downloads/output.m4b` and finally press enter. You can use any path/name instead of "~/Downloads/output.m4b".  The command should look like this:

[image]

That's it!

Also, this is not a duplicate... I hope that people can see how it is different than other posts about this topic.

Comment: Your answer might be better placed under the earlier question on this topic.

Comment: Was going to put it there, but I don't have enough points to do so.

Comment: You have enough reputation to post answers on protected questions. But check existing answers first whether your approach was already documented.